# How to pass all state values to the child component

Tags: reactjs

How to pass state values to the child component(CreateUser)

In CreateUser, I am trying to collect as props.data but getting "undefined"

> ```
> const One = (props) => {
>   const [info1, setInfo1] = useState({
>     firstname: "",
>     lastname: "",
>     email: "",
>     mobnumber: "",
>     password: "",
>   });
> //....
>
>   return (
>     <div>
>       <div className="container">
>         <div className="row ">
>           <div className="col-4">
>             <CreateUser
>               onInputChanged={onInputChanged}
>               data={props.info1}
>             ></CreateUser>
>           </div>
>           <div className="col">
>             <SelectParker />
>             <br />
>             <ActionButtons {...props} nextStep={validate} />
>           </div>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   );
> ```

// In CreateUser, I am trying to collect as props.data but getting "undefined"

Comment: You should use `data={info1}`. `info1` is a state not props.

Comment: Yes, Its working @DecPK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- {props.info1} refers props received by Component
- {info1} refers local variable/state defined in Component .

Use later to solve the "undefined" error i.e. data={info1}